# Importação de módulos e hierarquias - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pessoal estou com a seguinte dúvida.

Estou estudando importação de módulos e agarrei no seguinte problema, meu diretório está com a seguinte configuração:

[image: Estrutura Diretório]

Dúvida 1 -> Estou querendo importar os módulos de operação para imprimir e vice-versa

Dúvida 2 -> Importar o `outro_módulo.py` pra `imprimir.py` ou para um dos módulos de operação.

Já utilizei esse procedimento:

```
import imp  
arquivo, caminho, descrição = imp.find_module('módulo', ['/caminho/do/módulo/'])
nome_pro_módulo = imp.load_module('módulo', arquivo, caminho, descrição)
```

(funcionou mas se mudar de máquina pode dar conflito com relação ao caminho)

Utilizei este também:

```
import ..operacao import soma
```

Mas ocorre o seguinte erro: `Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Alguém saberia dizer onde estou errando?

Comment: Em qual arquivo você está efetuando a importação, no main.py?

Comment: Então no main.py consigo efetuar a importação normalmente. O problema é qd quero importar o módulo main.py pra imprimir ou se quiser importar o módulo soma.py pra imprimir... são nesses casos que ocorrem os erros listados.

Comment: Tem como postar os trechos de código? Está bem confuso e difícil entender o que está querendo fazer. Poste um trecho que funcionou da forma desejável e um que não funcionou, se possível.

Comment: Se estiver dentro de main.py essa importação funciona normalmente:        "from operacao.subt import Subtrai"

Comment: Agora se estiver dentro de imprimir.py e quero importar este mesmo módulo utilizei este caminho: "from ..operacao import Subtrai", aparece este erro: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py

Comment: Valeu, mas já tinha olhado essa question e não deu certo pelo q foi falado.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do módulo `imprimir` basta importar do seguinte modo:

```
from operacao import soma
```

Comment: Já tentei isso tb e não seu certo, fala que não existe esse módulo. Tentei até dessa forma: from .operacao import soma e tb não funcionou.